# Invalid JSON - DataTables - R ShinyProxy on Kubernetes

Tags: r, json, shiny, datatables, k3s

Currently, I am running an own developed R shiny package through shinyproxy on a local Kubernetes cluster (K3S). Within the package, tables are rendered with the DT-package, which is the shiny implementation of DataTable.

In some (random?) cases (which I cannot really reproduce), the tables give a following error:

```
DataTables warnings: table id=DataTable_Table_32 - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1
```

This error did not happen when the R-package is installed locally, and thus is happening as the results of the Kubernetes interaction or something like that.

I was wondering if any of you encountered a similar problem, and if so, how did you solve it?

Kind regards,

Comment: I don't know about your specific circumstances, but when I use Datatables with a PHP back-end I get this error when the server has sent back something other than json, usually nothing at all or an error message formatted as xml. Are you able to look at the network tab in your browser's developer console and see what the actual response from the server was?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I opened the network-tab, and the error is point to this: `r.send(i.hasContent && i.data || null)`, and it says `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()`. So I believe there is a setting somewhere that is causing a time-out, and I will investigate that more

Answer (score 0):

Solved, by adding `servlet.session.timeout: 86400` to the shinyproxy yaml